# Clicking a button to open dialog in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, dialog, frontend, react-modal

I'm working with [React MDL](https://tleunen.github.io/react-mdl) library, and I used pre-defined components like ***FABButton***

```
<FABButton>
  <Icon name="add"/>
</FABButton>
```

And it shows the button as in the image bellow:
[image]

Now, what I want is showing a dialog with the + icon... not as what happens here:

[image]

This happened after this code:

```
<FABButton>
  <AddingProject />
  <Icon name="add" />
</FABButton>
```

The class of dialog is as follows:

```
class AddingProject extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    this.handleOpenDialog = this.handleOpenDialog.bind(this);
    this.handleCloseDialog = this.handleCloseDialog.bind(this);
  }
  handleOpenDialog() {
    this.setState({
      openDialog: true
    });
  }

  handleCloseDialog() {
    this.setState({
      openDialog: false
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button colored onClick={this.handleOpenDialog} raised ripple>
          Show Dialog
        </Button>
        <Dialog open={this.state.openDialog} onCancel={this.handleCloseDialog}>
          <DialogTitle>Allow data collection?</DialogTitle>
          <DialogContent>
            <p>
              Allowing us to collect data will let us get you the information
              you want faster.
            </p>
          </DialogContent>
          <DialogActions>
            <Button type="button">Agree</Button>
            <Button type="button" onClick={this.handleCloseDialog}>
              Disagree
            </Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AddingProject;
```

The above code is with the required *import* statements

Comment: You should move the logic of opening/closing the dialog outside of your dialog component and open it by the `onClick` prop of your `<FABButton>`.

Comment: Why you add <AddingProject /> inside the FAB?

Comment: I'v tried things before like this: 
<FABButton onClick={() => AddingProject()}>
   <Icon name="add" />
</FABButton>
but some bugs occurred

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works with me....
**First step:** I added the component of the modal as follows:

```
<FABButton>
  <Icon name="add" />
</FABButton>
<ProjectModal>
```

**Second step:** I added this prop: `visible` for the component as here:

```
<ProjectModal visible={this.state.showDialog} />
```

And here you need to add `showDialog` to the states in your class with `false`.

```
state = {
  showDialog: false
};
```

Now, to step 3.
**Third step:** Add this part to your code, to be called when you click.

```
openModal = () => {
  this.setState({ showDialog: true });
};
```

On the other side, you need to implement `onClick` in the button as follows:

```
<FABButton onClick={this.openModal.bind(this)}>
  <Icon name="add" />
</FABButton>
```

**Fourth step:** In the modal/dialog class, you need to store the visible in a new state variable, which is here `showDialogModal`

```
constructor(props, context) {
super(props, context);
this.state = {
    showDialogModal: this.props.visible
  };
}
```

Now, you need to pass the changed state from the first class to the modal/dialog class, there are more than one option that React gives you, I used this one in fifth step.  **Fifth step:** use this React event `componentWillReceiveProps` as below.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
if (this.props.showDialogModal != nextProps.visible) {
  this.setState({
    showDialogModal: nextProps.visible
   });
  }
}
```

This will reflect any change in `visible` property from the first class to our new one here which is `showDialogModal`
Now in the render part, you need to check the docs of your components, here I started with React-Bootstrap.
**Sixth step:** use the `show` property in your component.

```
<Modal show={this.state.showDialogModal} onHide={this.closeModal}>
```

`onHide` is for closing the dialog, which makes you need to implement this too.

```
closeModal = () => {
  this.setState({ showDialogModal: false });
};
```

**Finally**, in the closing button, add this:

```
<Button onClick={this.closeModal.bind(this)}>Close</Button>
```

Good luck.

Comment: It's important to say that I used [React-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io) later, not the React-MDL components.